# Trying to test Enum's method

Tags: java, enums

Im trying to manually test my enum Rotation method next() but it's returning me nothing, most probably null. When I assign some variable tester = Rotation.CW0 and then call the method next(), the method should return CW90 but its returning nothing. COuld please smb take a look what I've done wrong in the code?

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rotation tester = Rotation.CW0;
        tester.next();
    }
}
public enum Rotation {

    CW0, CW90, CW180, CW270;

    // Calling rot.next() will return the next enumeration element
    // representing the next 90 degree clock-wise rotation after rot.
    public Rotation next()
    {
        if(this == CW0)
            return CW90;
        else if(this == CW90)
            return CW180;
        else if(this == CW180)
            return CW270;
        else if(this == CW270)
            return CW0;

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You don't assign the result of `next()` to a variable, so you're just throwing it basically.

Comment: Try printing the result: `System.out.println(tester.next());`

Comment: Use a `switch`. Please. And why use an `enum` for this when mathematics would seem to be much easier - you have a direction you are facing and you add some number of degrees; then you can test which quadrant you are in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rotation tester = Rotation.CW0;
        System.out.println(tester.next());
    }
}

public enum Rotation {

    CW0, CW90, CW180, CW270;

    public Rotation next() {
        switch (this) {
        case CW0:
           return CW90;
        case CW90:
           return CW180;
        case CW180:
           return CW270;
        case CW270:
           return CW0;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pshemo yep! just tried and corrected answer back :)

Comment: You're going to need a `default` on that `switch`. And your names are wrong.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. why? all possible values are enumerated. `this` cannot be null.

Comment: That doesn't matter. This will not compile. You **must** have a `default` in the `switch` or a `return` at the end. Try it...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes you're right. Corrected. Thanx!

Comment: I don't like the `return null`. If you think code cannot happen, then if it does it's an exceptional case. And exceptional cases deserve an...

Comment: @BoristheSpider agree. But this can lead to a very long discussion, and I believe here is not a place for. Otherwise, thanks for reviewing, I really appreciate.

Comment: @BoristheSpider btw, it is funny. Today, I've posted 1 answer to a question covering rather complicated issue, showing how skip list structure can serve a quick head access, when creating doubly-linked list is not possible. A few people commented. Here, I posted a very short and very simple snippet, errors in which, if they exist, are intuitive and easily recoverable in compile time. Tons of comments. Discussion, which doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Consider throwing an assertion error instead of returning null.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
enum Rotation {

    CW0, CW90, CW180, CW270;

    //here we know that that all enum variables are already created
    //so we can now set them up
    static{
        CW0.next = CW90;
        CW90.next = CW180;
        CW180.next = CW270;
        CW270.next = CW0;
    }

    private Rotation next;

    public Rotation next() {
        return this.next;
    }
}
```

OR little more cryptic

```
enum Rotation {

    CW0, CW90, CW180, CW270;

    //to prevent recreating array of values in each `next()` call
    private static final Rotation[] values = values();
    private static final int LENGTH = values.length;

    public Rotation next() {
        return values[(this.ordinal() + 1) % LENGTH];
    }
}
```

> but it's returning me nothing,

well `tester.next();` code returns you something but you are not storing and using it anywhere so maybe change your code to something like

```
Rotation tester = Rotation.CW0;
System.out.println(tester.next());
```

Comment: It feels wrong to have a non-final field like this in an enum (and I don't see an obvious way to make it final).

Comment: I don't like mutable variables on `enum`. This saves a few lines of code at the cost of making your `enum` mutable.

Comment: Well, I tried to minimize mutability by making `next` private which in reflection-free environment should work fine. But to make it more safe I added second version.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result of next() back to tester:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Rotation tester = Rotation.CW0;
    tester = tester.next();
    System.out.println(tester);
}

public enum Rotation {

    CW0, CW90, CW180, CW270;

    // Calling rot.next() will return the next enumeration element
    // representing the next 90 degree clock-wise rotation after rot.
    public Rotation next() {
        if (this == CW0) {
            return CW90;
        } else if (this == CW90) {
            return CW180;
        } else if (this == CW180) {
            return CW270;
        } else if (this == CW270) {
            return CW0;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are just printing "".. i think you meant to print tester: System.out.println(tester)

Comment: Yes...  I had that because I was just debugging so I can look at tester in my IDE after next() was call.  Good catch though!